# iPhone Custom Text Field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to create a simple calculator application.  I know a text field will display the calculations but is there any other way to display the results to the screen.  Or increase the text field.  I want a larger option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use UILabel instead of a UITextField.

If you need the textfield to show the keyboard you can move your textfield off screen and call [textfield becomesFirstRsponder]; from code.
But I would recommend a custom keyboard anyway.

Comment: So I can use a label to display results in real time?  Any links

Comment: I would recommend you to see all lectures of the stanford iphone programming course. http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=384233225 they have material on their site too. http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-winter

Answer (score 0):

For simple calculator application you can use `UITextField` or `UIlabel` for displaying your result. (Both are use for displaying output)

If you need to display static text with no editing features and no selection features, you should use a `UILabel`.

If you need selection or editing, use `UITextView`.